# Remove final modifier from 3rd party class

Tags: java, junit, javassist

I need to test write a JUnit test which tests the following line:

```
CSVRecord csvRecord = csvReader.readCsv(filename);
```

with `CSVRecord` from org.apache.commons.csv being a final class. If I try to tests this using EasyMock I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class pathname.FinalClass
at org.easymock.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:565)
at org.easymock.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
at ...
```

So I need to detach the "final" modifier from the `CSVRecord`. I tried this with javassist. However, I am running into an error. Have a look at this minimalistic example:

```
public class MyTestClass extends EasyMockSupport {

    @Mock
    private MockedClass mockedClass;

    @TestSubject
    private MyClass classUnderTest = new AmountConverter();

    @Test
    public void testName() throws Exception {
        ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
        CtClass ctClass = pool.get(FinalClass.class.getName());
        ctClass.defrost();
        removeFinal(ctClass);
        FinalClass finalClass = (FinalClass) EasyMock.createMock(ctClass.toClass());
        expect(mockedClass.foo()).andReturn(finalClass);

        replayAll();

        classUnderTest.foo();
    }

        static void removeFinal(CtClass clazz) throws Exception {
        int modifiers = clazz.getModifiers();
        if(Modifier.isFinal(modifiers)) {
            System.out.println("Removing Final");
            int notFinalModifier = Modifier.clear(modifiers, Modifier.FINAL);
            clazz.setModifiers(notFinalModifier);
        }
    }
}
```

with

```
public class MyClass {

    @Inject
    private MockedClass mockedClass;

    public void foo() {
        mockedClass.foo();
    }

    class MockedClass {

        FinalClass foo() {
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

and in it's own class file

```
public final class FinalClass {

}
```

I get the following error

```
javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "pathname/FinalClass"
at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1099)
at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1042)
at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1000)
at javassist.CtClass.toClass(CtClass.java:1224)
...
```

Comment: It's probably easier to mock `csvReader` and have it return a real `CSVRecord` when `readCsv(anyObject())` is invoked.

Comment: Please don't mock the types you don't own, you'll get into the trouble sooner or later. Write an Adapter around it instead. For more details please look https://github.com/testdouble/contributing-tests/wiki/Don%27t-mock-what-you-don%27t-own, https://8thlight.com/blog/eric-smith/2011/10/27/thats-not-yours.html and http://tech.findmypast.com/dont-mock-what-you-dont-own/

Comment: @SeverityOne: You can't do that. How would you intialize a CSVRecord?

Comment: @TheJavaGuy-IvanMilosavljević 1. With an adapter we shift the problem to another class. We would then have to test the readCsv-method there. 2. In your shared links CSVRecord has to be constructed. But CSVRecord has no accessable constructor...

Comment: @Chris311 Adapter implements an interface you define and that interface you can easily mock in unit tests. Interface is defined in the terms of your application's business logic and usually is much simpler than the interface of the 3rd party component. Real adapter itself is a very thin layer over CSVRecord and it's job is to translate requests from your application to the CSVRecord. Adapter thus becomes the only class which deals with CSVRecord. That way you can test your application logic easily. These kind of Adapters usually have no logic inside apart from translation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not change the definition of an already loaded class this way.

The problem is that the construct `FinalClass.class.getName()` or more specific, the class literal `FinalClass.class`, does already load the class to produce the associated `Class` object, the runtime representation of the loaded class.

Assuming that you are not using the class in any other way before that, you simply have to change the code to

```
ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
CtClass ctClass = pool.get("qualified.name.of.FinalClass");
ctClass.defrost();
removeFinal(ctClass);
FinalClass finalClass = (FinalClass) EasyMock.createMock(ctClass.toClass());
```

to change the definition of the class before its runtime representation is created.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is better to use an alternative for EasyMock instead of playing around with Javassist.

You may use Mockito 2 which supports mocking final classes: [Mock the unmockable: opt-in mocking of final classes/methods](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What's-new-in-Mockito-2#mock-the-unmockable-opt-in-mocking-of-final-classesmethods)

Another option would be to use PowerMock: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockFinal

Comment: Seem legit, but we are not allowed to use PowerMock in our projects. Same goes for Mockito, as we are using EasyMock and the developers came to an understanding that merging both is unwanted...